# How to Make Lotus Notes Items Display In InfoPath

Tags: import, csv, form-library, lotus-notes

I'm taking on a task from someone else and I'm trying to understand how this was done.

The old contractor took data from Lotus Notes ranging from MT No 803-809 (***there are thousands of items and I'm choosing to show a few***) and exported it to CSV (***this I know how it was done***). Maybe it was done differently but this is the scenario I'm going on.

The Lotus items 803-809 was then imported to a Form Library shown below:

[image]

**Below is what I'm trying to figure out based on the above shot**:

1. How did the old contractor make the Lotus Notes items 803-809 into InfoPath forms?
2. What is the best way and how to import the Lotus CSV file data into a Form Library like above?
3. Basically, how do I perform the same that was done in above screenshot?:)

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing he used the Dell Notes to SharePoint migration tool, which can convert Notes DB forms to InfoPath forms, I haven't done that specifically, but I've seen it in the tool. (I feel your Notes pain)